# Geometrical significance of Graph energy.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, network, adjacency-matrix

The following definition of the energy of graph is taken from an article entitled "Energy of Graphs. A few open problems and some suggestions" by Dragan Stevanovic of University of Nis, Serbia.

It says that the notion of energy of a graph is defined in $1978$ and originating from theoretical chemistry. For an $n$-vertex graph $G$ with adjacency matrix $A$ having eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq . . . \geq \lambda_n$, the energy $E(G)$ is defined as

$E(G) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i|$. It is related to the total $\pi$-electron energy in a molecule
represented by a (molecular) graph.

I am considering only simple undirected graphs and  have specifically, two questions as follows:

> Is the energy of a graph $G$ always greater than that of all its subgraphs? In other words, is the energy of a super graph always greater than its subgraphs?

> What is the geometrical significance of the energy of a graph representing social network like facebook? Or, what is the geometrical significance of the energy of a graph representing a food web in ecosystem?

Comment: This energy function here is closely related to the nuclear norm (or Schatten 1-norm) of the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The energy of a graph $G$ is always greater than the energy of an *induced* subgraph $H$ (where we take a subset of $G$'s vertices, and include all the edges $G$ had between them).

This follows from an interlacing result: if the adjacency matrix of $G$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \dots \ge \lambda_n$, and the adjacency matrix of $G-v$ (where we delete vertex $v$ and all its edges) has eigenvalues $\mu_1 \ge \mu_2 \ge \dots \ge \mu_{n-1}$, then
$$
   \lambda_1 \ge \mu_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \mu_2 \ge \dots \ge \lambda_{n-1} \ge \mu_{n-1} \ge \lambda_n.
$$
When $\mu_i$ is positive, $|\mu_i| \le |\lambda_i|$; when $\mu_i$ is negative, $|\mu_i| \le |\lambda_{i+1}|$. This tells us that the sum $|\mu_1| + \dots + |\mu_{n-1}|$ is less than $|\lambda_1| + \dots + |\lambda_n|$: the energy of $G-v$ is less than the energy of $G$.

In general, for an induced subgraph, we may delete multiple vertices, in which case we just apply this result repeatedly.

For non-induced subgraphs, this might not apply. Examples 4.5 and 4.6 in the paper [*Graph Energy Change due to Edge Deletion*](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/%7Eso/gec_ded.pdf) by Day and So prove that the energy of $K_n-e$ is less than the energy of $K_n$ (where $e$ is an arbitrary edge) but the energy of $K_{n,n}-e$ is greater than the energy of $K_{n,n}$ (where $e$ is an arbitrary edge), so the change can go in both directions.

Comment: By combining the result you suggested and the Example 4.5, the result must be also be true for any arbitrary subgraphs excluding certain classes of graphs, like bipartite graphs as suggested by 4.6.

Comment: The inequality on induced subgraphs is strict except when $G$ and $G-v$ have the same edges (that is, when $v$ is an isolated vertex). So if we rule out isolated vertices, then only spanning subgraphs (with the same vertex set, but fewer edges) can have energy higher than the supergraph. The paper doesn't really suggest anything conclusive one way or the other for those, just partial results (Theorem 3.6)

Comment: Well!. Noted...$